# Binary tree char count and concat

Tags: tree, ocaml, binary-tree

A binary tree has the type 'a tree in ocaml, as follows:

```
type 'a tree = Leaf of 'a
         | Fork of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
let t3 = Fork ("Hello", Leaf "World", Leaf "!")
```

How would I write a function t_charcount that takes a string tree as input and count the total number of characters that the values contain. Type of the function is: string tree -> int.

```
    t_charcount t3 gives int = 11.
```

How would I write a function:

write a function t_concat that will concatenate together the values of a string tree. Type of this function is: string tree -> string

```
   t_concat t3 gives string = "HelloWorld!".
```

Answer (score 1):

> How would I write a function t_charcount that takes a string tree as input and count the total number of characters that the values contain

Use the structural induction - think about the base case (e.g., how many characters in a leaf node), then think about how you will join results from the left and right subtree in the `Fork` node, this is the general skeleton for you:

```
let t_charcount tree = 
  let rec loop tree sum = match tree with
   | Leaf x -> ...base case...
   | Fork (x,t1,t2) -> ...induction case.. in
 loop tree 0
```

> write a function t_concat that will concatenate together the values of a string tree. Type of this function is: string tree -> string

You should use the same approach as with the `charcount` function, except instead of accumulating result in an integer, you should accumulate result in a string, using the concatenation operator `^`.

P.S. Do not expect, that people will do your homework.

Comment: Would I have to use the String.length function to count the chars? Do I necessarily need a helper function? Also, I am not sure what the use for "sum" is?

Comment: Sum is an arbitrary chosen name for a function parameter in which you will accumulate the total number of characters on your tree.  And yes, you should use the String.length function.